# sharedElment transition using fragments not transitioning

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

```
AndroidStudio 2.3 Beta 1
```

I am trying to get transitions work with fragments, how the image I am using doesn't transition. It just pop up as normal.

I have created a simple App to try and get this to work. I have 2 fragments `ListMovieFragment` and `DetailMovieFragment`. And 1 `MainActivity`.

The user will click the image in `ListMovieFragment` to transition to `DetailMovieFragment`.

This is my Transition xml change_image_transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <changeImageTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

ListMovieFragment:

```
public class ListMovieFragment extends Fragment {
    public interface MovieSelectedListener {
        void onMovieSelected(int movieId);
    }
    private MovieSelectedListener mMovieSelectedListener;

    public ListMovieFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mMovieSelectedListener = (MovieSelectedListener)context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mMovieSelectedListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        final ImageView ivMoviePoster = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivMoviePoster);

        ivMoviePoster.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mMovieSelectedListener != null) {
                    mMovieSelectedListener.onMovieSelected(12345);
                }
            }
        });

        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/qjiskwlV1qQzRCjpV0cL9pEMF9a.jpg")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_poster)
                .centerCrop()
                .crossFade()
                .into(ivMoviePoster);

        return view;
    }
}
```

DetailMovieFragment

```
public class DetailMovieFragment extends Fragment {
    public DetailMovieFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

        final ImageView ivMovieDetailPoster = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivMovieDetailPoster);

        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/qjiskwlV1qQzRCjpV0cL9pEMF9a.jpg")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_poster)
                .centerCrop()
                .crossFade()
                .into(ivMovieDetailPoster);

        return view;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListMovieFragment.MovieSelectedListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main, new ListMovieFragment(), "listmoviefragment");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMovieSelected(int movieId) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            /* Get the fragments that will be using the transition */
            ListMovieFragment listMovieFragment = new ListMovieFragment();
            DetailMovieFragment detailMovieFragment = new DetailMovieFragment();

            /* Inflate the transition */
            Transition changeTransition = TransitionInflater
                    .from(MainActivity.this)
                    .inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform);

            Transition explodeTransition = TransitionInflater
                    .from(MainActivity.this)
                    .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode);

            /* Set the exit and return on the source fragment (ListMovieFragment) */
            listMovieFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(changeTransition);
            listMovieFragment.setExitTransition(explodeTransition);

            /* Set the enter on the destination fragment (MovieDetailFragment) */
            detailMovieFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(changeTransition);
            detailMovieFragment.setEnterTransition(explodeTransition);

            /* Get the shared imageview from the source fragment (MovieListFragment) */
            final ImageView ivSharedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivMoviePoster);

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main, new DetailMovieFragment(), "detailmoviefragment");
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("detailmoviefragment");
            fragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(ivSharedImage, getResources().getString(R.string.transition_poster_image));
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        else {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main, new DetailMovieFragment(), "detailmoviefragment");
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("detailmoviefragment");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

The layout for ListMovieFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp">

    <ImageView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ivMoviePoster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder_poster"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_poster_image">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout for DetailMovieFragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="me.androidbox.fragmenttransitions.detail.DetailMovieFragment">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMovieDetailPoster"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_poster_image"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

The string name for the transition name:

```
<string name="transition_poster_image">imagePoster</string>
```

The implementation seems simple so I think my mistake is something i'm overlooking.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two problems in your code, inside your `onMovieSelected` method:

1. You're creating a **new instance** of `ListMovieFragment` and then apply transition logic to it. 
   But you forgot that you already have the instance of this fragment (you were created it in `onCreate` method). 
   So you need to retrieve the existing `ListMovieFragment` object from `FragmentManager`, and apply your transitions to it.
2. You're applying transition logic to one instance of `DetailMovieFragment`, but then suddenly replacing the `ListMoveFragment` with the new one.

So your fixed `onMovieSelected` method will be:

```
@Override
public void onMovieSelected(int movieId) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        /* Get the fragments that will be using the transition */
        ListMovieFragment listMovieFragment = (ListMovieFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("listmoviefragment");
        DetailMovieFragment detailMovieFragment = new DetailMovieFragment();

        /* Inflate the transition */
        Transition changeTransition = TransitionInflater
                .from(MainActivity.this)
                .inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform);

        Transition explodeTransition = TransitionInflater
                .from(MainActivity.this)
                .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode);

        /* Set the exit and return on the source fragment (ListMovieFragment) */
        listMovieFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(changeTransition);
        listMovieFragment.setExitTransition(explodeTransition);

        /* Set the enter on the destination fragment (MovieDetailFragment) */
        detailMovieFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(changeTransition);
        detailMovieFragment.setEnterTransition(explodeTransition);

        /* Get the shared imageview from the source fragment (MovieListFragment) */
        final ImageView ivSharedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivMoviePoster);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main, detailMovieFragment, "detailmoviefragment");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("detailmoviefragment");
        fragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(ivSharedImage, getResources().getString(R.string.transition_poster_image));
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main, new DetailMovieFragment(), "detailmoviefragment");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("detailmoviefragment");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Now this should work.

**P.S.** I've used your code and run it, and noticed you have some strange transitions, so if you will have some issues, check this [great article](https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb#.he5ba2vci), how to make smooth and user-friendly transitions with fragments:)

Comment: Thanks this as helped.

Comment: After making all the corrections. The transition look great entering the detailFragment. But when the back button is press the transition doesn't transition. I thought this happened automatically when fragment are popped from the backstack. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you probably need to add return transition to `detailMovieFragment`, like this: `detailMovieFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(changeTransition);`. Guess it should resolve your problem.

Comment: That didn't actually work. However, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hm, one thing - what if you will remove your `onBackPressed` method implementation from `MainActivity`? But leave the return transition.

Comment: I have tested with the onBackPressed and without it and the result is the same. I have a git animation on this new post here where you can see what is going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355756/return-transition-not-working-correctly-when-using-fragment-shared-tranistions

Answer (score 3):

Don't create new object Fragment while adding to fragment transaction,reuse the existing fragment in which you applied the enter and exit transitions.

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListMovieFragment.MovieSelectedListener {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                if(savedInstanceState == null) {
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        ListMovieFragment listMovieFragment = new ListMovieFragment();
                        Transition changeTransition = TransitionInflater
                                .from(MainActivity.this)
                                .inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform);

                        Transition explodeTransition = TransitionInflater
                                .from(MainActivity.this)
                                .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode);
                        listMovieFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(changeTransition);
                        listMovieFragment.setExitTransition(explodeTransition);
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        //don't create new  ListMovieFragment use existing listMovieFragment instance
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main, listMovieFragment, "listmoviefragment");
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }else {
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main, new ListMovieFragment(), "listmoviefragment");
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMovieSelected(int movieId) {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    /* Get the fragments that will be using the transition */
                    ListMovieFragment listMovieFragment = new ListMovieFragment();
                    DetailMovieFragment detailMovieFragment = new DetailMovieFragment();

                    /* Inflate the transition */
                    Transition changeTransition = TransitionInflater
                            .from(MainActivity.this)
                            .inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform);

                    Transition explodeTransition = TransitionInflater
                            .from(MainActivity.this)
                            .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode);

                    /* Set the exit and return on the source fragment (ListMovieFragment) */
                    listMovieFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(changeTransition);
                    listMovieFragment.setExitTransition(explodeTransition);

                    /* Set the enter on the destination fragment (MovieDetailFragment) */
                    detailMovieFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(changeTransition);
                    detailMovieFragment.setEnterTransition(explodeTransition);

                    /* Get the shared imageview from the source fragment (MovieListFragment) */
                    final ImageView ivSharedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivMoviePoster);

                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    //don't create new  DetailMovieFragment use existing detailMovieFragment instance
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main, detailMovieFragment, "detailmoviefragment");
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("detailmoviefragment");
                    fragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(ivSharedImage, getResources().getString(R.string.transition_poster_image));
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
                else {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main, new DetailMovieFragment(), "detailmoviefragment");
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("detailmoviefragment");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                }
                else {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks this has helped